# Libgdx Android Sdk accessing external web api

Tags: android, api, libgdx

I am trying to make a game on Android Studio using Libgdx and want to be able to access external web apis. I am wondering whether this is still possible while running Libgdx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can still use other API's. Libgdx only isolates UI layer from your native android environment with it's glSurfaceView. If you implement proper interfaces for accesing other API's like Admob, Parse, Google Play Services or whatever you want, you can use it all.

I suggest you to read this document which can help and enlight you :

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code

Comment: Coskun Thanks very much, gives me somewhere to start.